# Expectation of a function with normal probability distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation

I have a random variable X that is normally distributed and a function that takes values based on the range of X. I want to calculate the expected value of this function. The function is as follows

$$ G(X) \begin{cases} 
    0 , &\text{if }  x\leqslant 0 \\
    x , &\text{if } 0 \leqslant x \leqslant\ Q \\
    Q , &\text{if } x>Q 
\end{cases}$$

I can write the integral for the expected value in parts as follows and solve for it.

$$ E[G(X)] = \int_{0}^Q xf(x)\,dx + \int_{Q}^\infty Qf(x) \,dx$$

where f(x) is the probability distribution function of X ~ N($\mu$,$\sigma$)

But the integral turns out to be quite lengthy and I was wondering if there was a shorter way to do it using special functions like delta function, because I am doing a course in operations and would have to use this frequently.

Comment: If $(\mu,\sigma^2)=(0,1)$, the PDF $f$ is the standard normal PDF $\varphi$, $xf(x)=-f'(x)$, and $f(x)$ has no primitive in terms of usual functions, except if the standard normal CDF $\Phi$ is considered as such, hence $$E(G(X))=\varphi(0)-\varphi(Q)+Q\cdot(1-\Phi(Q))$$ The general case $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ can be written down similarly. Reading the WP page on the normal distributions seems to be a *must* for you.

Comment: Hi did, the same method that you describe becomes a little long when done for a non-standard normal distribution. I was wondering if this can be shortened?

Comment: What is long is the final formula $$E(G(X))=\sigma(\varphi(-\mu/\sigma)-\varphi((Q-\mu)/\sigma))+\mu(\Phi((Q-\mu)/\sigma)-\Phi(-\mu/\sigma))+Q\cdot(1-\Phi((Q-\mu)/\sigma))$$ but not the method...